# JQuery ajax call fails when emulating click with .trigger()

Tags: jquery

On my page I add an input field with ajax when the user clicks a button and I remove it when the user clicks another button. However I want to allow the user to remove the field when pressing escape as well and that's where things get weird. I use this code to emulate the click on the specified elements, I've also tried using .click() but there's no difference there.

```
$("#Field").keydown(function(Event) {
    if(Event.which == 13) //Enter
        $(".Add").trigger("click");
    else if(Event.which == 27) //Escape
        $(".Remove").trigger("click");
});
```

When I click the button manually with my mouse the code executes fine but when I press escape the ajax call errors out and the only information I get from the error callback is the string "error".

I've checked the message sent and the same post data is sent in both cases but the ajax call just doesn't reach the server when I emulate the click in my code instead of clicking it manually.

When I press the enter key however, everything works just as expected and there is no difference between clicking the button and pressing the enter key.

This is the code that gets executed when the user clicks the button or presses any key it's just an ajax request using JQuery

```
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/index.php/main/handleclick",
              data: "id=" + Id + "&class=" + Class + "&value=" + Field,

              success: function(Response, Message){
                if(Response != "undefined")
                    HandleResponse(Response, Message);
                },
```

I don't know if I was clear enough when I described my problem, the script always ends up here, it doesn't matter if I click the button or press enter or escape. The problem is that when I press any other key except escape the code works as it should.

Thanks 
Kerp

Comment: Please show the function that gets executed when click fires

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers:

- Since the Return key works, `.trigger("click")` should work (there is no reason why it should work for one key but not the other).
- Wrap the bodies of the `if()` statements in `{}` to avoid unexpected errors.
- Use `console.log()` to see what code is called. If your browser doesn't support this, add a `<div id="#debug">`, style it to an absolute position above the page and use `$('#debug').text()` to log.
- You're using `.Remove` which matches the class, not the ID. Are you sure this is what you want? Is there really only one element with that class?
- Use you're browser's debugger to make sure the correct code is executed.